# Running npm install in Console of an Azure Function (node.js) on Linux environment gives error

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I have a node.js based Azure Function created under Linux Platform using a Shared App Service Plan (also Linux Environment). Practically anything that I type in the Console returns the below message

I am not able to install any packages.

> npm -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
>
> npm -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

[image: Practically anything that I type in the Console returns the below message]

The other settings are as below:

```
      {
        "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
        "value": "~2",
        "slotSetting": false
      },
      {
        "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
        "value": "node",
        "slotSetting": false
      },
      {
        "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
        "value": "8.10.0",
        "slotSetting": false
      }
```

I changed the WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION from 10 to 8.10.0 above because I had similar issues in another function and setting this made it work. That function was Windows based however and 4 times expensive so I wanted to save some money.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is stupid because its not so obvious and there is no documentation.

For Nodejs Function Apps that are Linux based, the Console Window is useless and does nothing. SSH window is to be used and **should be opened in a new tab** for 'npm install' to work. The phrase in **BOLD** above is the key to make it work.